# How to add analyzer to the nested fields in elasticsearch spring data?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have schema which actually includes the nested type as shown below.

This is main schema.

```
@Document(indexName = "agreement")
public class PromotionSearchSchema {

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private Promotion promotionproduct;

}
```

Now, the Promotion is the another entity inside main schema. So i have marked it as nested type. In the Promotion entity i'm trying to add analyzer as shown below

```
@Setting(settingPath = "es-config/elastic-analyzer.json")
public class Promotion {

 @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "autocomplete_index", searchAnalyzer = "autocomplete_search")
    private String promotionDescription;

}
```

This is my elastic-analyzer.json

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 1,
        "max_gram": 20
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "autocomplete_search": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      },
      "autocomplete_index": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_filter"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i do like, it's not at all creating the complete mappings in the Elasticsearch. It's just creating as shown below

```
{
  "agreement" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  }
}
```

So my question is how to add the analyzers in the nested type. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `@Setting` annotation to the top level entitty.

Comment: OK, then no need to add to its child i guess?